# Facebook oauth login always goes straight to authentication bypassing "Continue as xyz" page

Tags: facebook, xamarin, authentication, oauth

I'm trying to implement "Login with Facebook" for my app.
I've successfully implemented this with oauth2 for Google.
However, with Facebook, it always pushes me straight to the Authentication page, rather than to the Login as XYZ page as with the pinterest screenshot example here:
[Login with Facebook as it's meant to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmDcV.png)

I'm also reasonably confident I have the facebook settings correct (as I said, everything works, except that I always jump to full email/pwd authentication).
Here is my configuration: [How my facebook oauth settings are configured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVkcE.jpg)

I'm working in Xamarin, using Xamarin.Auth for my OAuth package.  
Is this something I have to use the Facebook SDK for? (I don't see how this would be).

What am I missing?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Which SDK do you use? Some native SDK FB and Google or something like Xamarin.Auth?

Comment: moljac - I'm using Xamarin.Auth.  btw... I get the same behavior in your sample too...